# excel, pivot table, filter, sum, need to filter to where non-zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, see below. How can I filter this pivot table to where Sum of Not Compliant is not 0. I cannot add filters to any of the Sum columns in this take. The final column in this pivot table is a calculated field that I added to show the percentage of Non-Compliant.

I thought it would be easy to add a filter to the pivot table and just filter to where the sum of non compliant is non-zero. However, excel does not allow this. I also tried to filter to where the calculated field was greater than zero. However, excel did not allow this either. Not sure what to do. This is excel related, please approve question.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must click the filter on the 'Row Labels' cell, then choose Value Filters>Greater than, and configure like this:

[image]

i.e.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply multiple filters a quick trick is to click on the cell directly to the right of you pivot tables' header row, the add an auto-filter (or press Alt, A, T). This will add a filter to all columns in your pivot table.

Before.

[image]

After

[image]

Best Regards,
Brad